# Handling server side errors in javascript fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch

I'm making a script which has server side validation.  When validation fails I have the script throw an exception server side.  I want to access the message in the exception when the response reaches the client side, but I'm having trouble with that.  If I console.log the `data` I can see the exception, but I want to access it in the `catch` so I can push the error message to an HTML element on the page.

```
    fetch(/* Posting to some PHP script */).then(function(data) {
        
        // Logic here when success  
        console.log(data) // Shows error msg when there is an error 

        
    }).catch(function() {
        // Error Handling, I want to push the error msg to HTML element here             
    });
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Throw the error. It will be caught in the `.catch()` and you can manipulate it there

```
fetch(/* Posting to some PHP script */)
    .then(function(data) {
        // Logic here when success 
        console.log(data) // Shows error msg when there is an error
        if(data.error){ // Or whatever condition you need to detect there's an error
            throw data.error; // This will be caught in the catch() below
        }
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        // You have your error here with the message from the server, display it in the HTML          
    });
```